# How to unit test "with using" translate filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

Here is my filter X, which uses the standard translate filter.

```js
.filter('X', function ($filter) {
      return function(value) {
        ...
        ... $filter('translate')(...);
        ...
        return result;
```

Here is my module for the translation:

```js
  angular.module('translateModule', ['ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
    .config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
      $translateProvider.translations('de', {
        "HEADER": "Finden Sie die Stelle:",
        "TITLE" : "Suchen",
        ...
      )};
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de').fallbackLanguage('de');
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
```

When i want to test my filter X, **the filter 'translate' is unfamiliar** for the test. So when "TITLE" is searched, $filter('translate') gives "TITLE" back instead of "Suchen".

So i want to let 'translate' also run while testing.. What should i do? This is how my test partially looks like:

```js
it('should translate ...', function () {
  // Arrange.
  var value = 50;

  // Act.
  var result = $filter('X')(value);

  // Assert.
  expect(result).toEqual(....);
});
```

I have tried to add the module in my test like this:

```js
beforeEach(module('translateModule'));
```

but still does not work..

Comment: What exactly are you testing? Because it looks like you are testing that this `$translateProvider` is doing what it should, which is not really a "unit test". A unit test of that filter would test that `$filter` was called with the string `"translate"`. Another test would test that the result of calling `$filter('translate')` was itself called with whatever arguments you're passing.

Comment: i am testing the functionality of X filter + translate filter, i would like to test both together